# Pex and "\0" what is the correct name for this?

Tags: c#, string, pex

I am using Pex and keeps throwing "\0" at my string parameters. Through a little testing I found that it is some sort of end of string?

I am looking for the official name for this to learn more about it but google is shallowing all the white spaces of "\0" making it a 0 and end of string does not turn up much either.

Interstingly the lenght of strings are
"\0" , lenght 1, display ""
"\0\0" , lenght 2, display ""
"1234\056709", length 10, display "1234"

thx for the hints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Null-terminated string](http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-20/ass20_2.html)

Answer (score 1):

\0 is the escape for the NUL character.